# How may I find the most recently modified file(s)?

Tags: bash, scripting, ksh, timestamps

In a directory, I have a number of files, and I need to do something with the most recently modified file with a `.txt` suffix.

Ideally, I'd like to do

```
myutility "$newest"
```

in the end, where `$newest` would be the pathname of the most recently modified file.

It would be nice if this additionally could be generalised so that I could get the most recently modified file with a `.txt` suffix in a directory hierarchy, and even better if I could get the, say, five most recently modified files so that I could use

```
myutility "${newest[@]}"
```

to run my utility on the five most recently modified `.txt` files in a whole directory hierarchy.

A solution using `bash` or `ksh93` would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you tagged the question `bash` and `ksh`, with `zsh` and glob qualifiers:

```
print **/*.txt(.om[1,5])
```

prints the first 5 plain files (`.`) with `.txt` extension, ordered by ascending modification time (`om`)

ex.

```
print **/*.txt(.om[1,5])
dir/file1.txt file2.txt dir/file.txt File1.txt File2.txt
```

Comment: I should really read up on the zsh shell's operators etc. someday soon... How would you go about getting the results into an array? I realise that just using the expansion on the command line of a utility would work, but just for completeness... Same syntax as bash and ksh93?

Comment: @Kusalananda yes I believe you can do a ksh/bash style `newfiles=( **/*.txt(.om[1,5]) )` in zsh (although that may not be the recommended way - I'm just feeling my way into zsh myself)

Answer (score 3):

You can list the files by modification time (or creation or access) with ls.

simply say

```
ls -t *.txt | head -n5
```

to get the last 5 recent .txt files

You can feed it into myutility with $() or xargs.

```
ls -t *.txt | head -n5 | xargs myutility
```

If you need the recursion, you can use find.

```
find -type f -iname "*.txt" | xargs ls -t | head -n5 | xargs myutility
```

(possible issue: you have to have at least one .txt file for this to work. you can fix it, but it's the cleanest solution).

EDIT: OP wanted to know how to handle filenames with spaces. Here is one solution:

```
find -type f -iname "*.txt" | xargs ls -t | head -n5 | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 myutility
```

If you want to solve the possible issue mentioned above you can check for the files before-head with `find ..... | egrep '.*' || exit` or simply include some nonsensical filename to ls  and ignore the warning like `xargs ls -t ''`.

Comment: This requires that the filenames do not contain whitespace characters such as space or newline. It also requires GNU `find`.

Comment: of course. I wrote it this way for simplicity. You can easily fix it by using zero delimiter. option -0 for xargs and print0 for find.

Comment: Good people never use whitespace in filenames anyway... :-D

Comment: I don't think I mentioned anything about the character set used for the filenames in the question, apart from them ending with `.txt`. So there can be no assumptions made. Good people write code to support any valid Unix filename. Using `-print0` and `-0` with `find` and `xargs` will help partway through the pipeline (if you have tools that support these options), but you'll have the same issue when you get to `ls` and `head` later, especially if the filenames contain newlines.

Comment: no insult was intended. I hoped you are here to learn, and simple is better than complex if you want to learn. Extended solution included for you.

Comment: I know that [parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) is bad, but this solution is so good. This is exactly how I do it.

Answer (score 0):

It may look ugly but using `find` to get files is the most robust method, avoiding issues with spaces & other special characters in names. You get a list of modified times + files, sort it by recent, get the top *n* (here `5`), drop the times leaving only filenames, and pass it to your script:

```bsh
find dir -iname '*.txt' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -znr | head -z -n 5 | grep -zPo '^\S+\s+\K[\S\s]*' | xargs -0r myutility
```

---

If you're on an older version of `coreutils` (< v8.25 `head` won't support `-z`) or `grep` (< v2.25 has [a bug](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36090268/315024)), you can use a script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
flimit=5
filenames=()
while (( flimit-- )) && IFS=$'\t' read -r -d $'\0' mtime filename; do
    filenames=("${filenames[@]}" "$filename")
done < <(find -name '*.txt' -printf '%T@\t%p\0' | sort -znr)
if [[ ${#filenames[@]} -gt 0 ]]; then
    myutility "${filenames[@]}"
else
    >&2 echo no files found
fi
```