# Shell - Find the latest file which matches a given pattern

Tags: bash, shell, files, solaris, date

I have the following files.

```
root@VMBOX:/client# ls -lrt /client/*/ver* /client/*/*/ver*  
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:54 /client/folder299/version_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:58 /client/ifolder299/ifolder/version_a
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:58 /client/ifolder300/ifolder1/version_b
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:58 /client/ifolder301/ifolder2/version_c
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:58 /client/ifolder302/ifolder3/version_d
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 19 13:35 /client/folder300/version_2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 19 13:35 /client/folder301/version_3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul 19 13:36 /client/folder302/version_4
```

I am trying to get the latest version file for a pattern matching an ID. Example is shown below.

```
root@VMBOX:/client# ls -lrt /client/*/ver* /client/*/*/ver*   | grep 299
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:54 /client/folder299/version_1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:58 /client/ifolder299/ifolder/version_a
```

The latest version is version_a in the above example.

```
root@VMBOX:/client# ls -lrt /client/*/ver* /client/*/*/ver*   | grep 299 | tail -1
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  5 18:58 /client/ifolder299/ifolder/version_a
```

I am told that this approach is not good to find a file ([Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls) )and am looking for an alternative way like https://stackoverflow.com/a/26766782/9316558. Please let me know if something is not clear.

Update:

From below answer by Jasen, I could get the latest file in the path /client

```
find /client -path "*299*" -printf "%T@ %P\n" | sort -n | tail -1
```

But, the above command gives the latest file. I am looking for finding the latest version file.

Comment: Will the latest version file always be the one that sorts last, or should file timestamps be used, or some other scheme?

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, the latest version file will always be the one that sorts last. I mean the one that is created recently.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. Sorts last, by name? ... taking into account that `version_3` sorts _after_ `version_10`.

Comment: @Raj: Does it *have* to be bash? If you would write your script in Zsh, you could do for instance a `files=( /client/*299*/ver*(Nom) )` to get an array of files sorted in ascending order by modification time (_o_ means sorting, _m_ means modification time, _N_ causes an empty array to be generated if no matching files exist). If you need descending order, use `(^Nom)` instead.

Comment: @Kusalananda The order in which I need the version file is sorting by time. For example, if version_a is created recently, I would need it.

Comment: @user1934428 I would like to use default bash for this operation as I am not authorized to use/install any external module.

Comment: Please re-tag your Question to Solaris, as it's apparent from comments that you're only connecting *from* Linux, then running `find` on Solaris.

Comment: Does this solve your issue?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/456957/how-may-i-find-the-most-recently-modified-files

Answer (score 2):

you can combine find and sort

```
find -path "some pattern" -printf "%T@ %P\n" | sort -n | tail -1
```

Comment: Sorry. Should I be running the command like this?
    `find -name "299" -printf "%T@ %P\n" | sort -n | tail -1`

Comment: possibly `-path "*299*"` it understands the normal shell wildcards

Comment: it turns out `-name` was wrong and you need `-path` th match on directory names. answer edited.

Comment: yeah, you can add a start location  before `-path` if you want search other than the current directory, see the man page for find - there's many other options.

Comment: Thanks for the update. The command seems to work if executed from inside the folder where I need this value from.

    `root@RV-VMBOX:/client# find -path "*299*" -printf "%T@ %P\n" | sort -n | tail -1`
    `1530797283.5560000000 ifolder299/ifolder/version_a`

In my case, I need to execute this command remotely as a user of the system. So, I understand that this will search in the home directory of the above user, where this folder doesn't exist. Is there a way in which we can extend the -path's argument to be more precise with the path?

Comment: Thank you. This is working on linux systems. But, I need to execute this command remotely on a solaris OS unix system, where I am observing errors. I will try to look into man page. Thanks again.

On Linux : `root@RV-VMBOX:/# find /client -path "*299*" -printf "%T@ %P\n" | sort -n | tail -1`
`1530797283.5560000000 ifolder299/ifolder/version_a`

On Unix:
`root@solarisserver:~# find /client -path "*299*" -printf "%T@ %P\n" | sort -n | tail -1`
`find: bad option -path`
`find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list`

Comment: @Raj [POSIX **6** `find`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) does not have a `-path` option.  It was added in [POSIX 7.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html)  Before POSIX 7, the `-path` option was a vendor-specific, non-portable extension. Which version of Solaris?  Depending on the version, you might have GNU find as `/usr/bin/gfind` or /usr/sfw/bin/find`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Thanks for the response. Solaris version - Solaris 11.3. I could learn that the _gfind_ mimics the _find_ behavior.

Comment: @Jasen I found that, if there is another file created after _version_ file is updated, the above find command shows the other file. Could you please help me in narrowing it to find latest _version_ file.